# Validating Form with Javascript (Simple Test)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```
var name = document.getElementById('contact-name'),
    email = document.getElementById('contact-email'),
    phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone'),
    message = document.getElementById('contact-message');


function checkForm() {
  if (name.value == '') {
    alert('test');
  }

}
```

I was simply trying to make sure everything was working before I began learning actual client-side validation.

Here is the HTML

```
   <form role='form' name='contactForm' action='#' method="POST" id='contact-form'>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-name">First and Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="contactName" placeholder="Enter your name.." pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="contactPhone" name="contactPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"  required'>
          </div>   

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for='contactMessage'>Your Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter a brief message" name='contactMessage' id='contact-message' required></textarea>
          </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value='Submit' onclick='checkForm()'>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
```

I took the required attribute off, and if I leave the name field empty it goes right to the other one when i click submit. To check whether javascript was working at all, i did an basic onclick function that worked.

Maybe someone can explain to me what is wrong with the checkForm function. Thanks in advance.

P.S The form-group and form-control classes belong to bootstrap

Comment: Are you receiving any errors from `checkForm()`? If so, which errors? It may be that you're trying to retrieve the elements before they actually exist.

Comment: Is your code in the `<head>`? If it is you must wait until the DOM is ready, or you can put your script tag at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: No error as far as I know. my script tags are all before the closing body tag.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution? What are you trying to achieve and what behavior of your app prevents you from doing so? How do you use the `checkForm()` function? I don't see any invocations.

Comment: I edited the HTML to show the entire form. I put the onclick on the submit button

I'm just trying to make everything work before I learn to validate the form entirely. the alert('test') doesnt show up when I leave the name field blank

Comment: you are showing us individual bits of code and we're unable tell how they are interacting.  Please post a *complete* sample of your project here, or create a jsfiddle or similar, so we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: I think this should include everything

 http://jsfiddle.net/gfk5x/

if i click submit without typing anything into the name field, it will go on to the next without alerting

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to this:

```
   var contactName = document.getElementById('contact-name'),
       email = document.getElementById('contact-email'),
       phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone'),
       message = document.getElementById('contact-message');


    function checkForm() {
      if (contactName.value === '') {
        alert('test');
      }

    }
```

Comment: This will not prevent font submission and will not work at all. What will happen instead is that when user fills the name field and clicks the submit button, the error message will pop-up.

Comment: @necka7 I agree with point 2 and 3. However the value is retrieved within the checkForm function. So the value will be the current.

Comment: The form will still submit. However the error won't popup if the contact name is filled.

Comment: I do not see the retrieval command within the function, can you please elaborate?

Comment: What is being retrieved is the element not the value. When retrieving the value (contactName.value) the property will contain the current value not the one on load.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Hobbes, thank you for editing your question, now I can understand your problem.
Your code faces <s>three</s> two issues.

1. <s>Your control flow. If you want to validate your field, you have to obtain its value upon validation. You instead populate variable name when the page loads, but the user will enter the text only after that. Hence you need to add var `someVariableName = document.getElementById(...);` to the beginning of the `checkForm()` function.</s>
2. global variables. Please do not use them like that, it is a good design to avoid global variables as much as possible, otherwise you bring upon yourself the danger of introducing side effects (or suffering their impact, which happens in your situation). The global context window already contains a variable `name` and you cannot override that. See `window.name` in your console. You can of course use `var name = ...` inside the function or a block.
3. Even if you fix the above, you will still submit the form. You can prevent the form submission if you end your `checkForm()` function with `return false;`

For clarity I append the partial javascript that should work for you:

```
function checkForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById('contact-name');   
  if (name.value == '') {
    alert('test');
    return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT: As Eman Z pointed out, the part 1 of the problem does not really prevent the code from working as there's being retrieved an address of an object (thanks, Eman Z!),

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/5E6cs/4/

Comment: Of course, so stupid of me! change `onsubmit='checkForm()'` to `onsubmit='return checkForm()'`

Comment: Hmm, still doesnt seem to work for me. Can you provide me with a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vL2tL/ here it is, but it shows json with error message, I guess that's because of the form. Did you try placing the code in the source file? And if so, what's the behavior?

Comment: hmm okay, So i placed the code in script tags above my form and it worked... Got the alert message after leaving the name field blank.

I dont understand why though

Comment: If you're puzzled by stuff not working in jsfiddle, I suggest the reason for this kind of behavior is security: you would not want your page with form to be submitted by other button than you originally intended as there can be scripts bound to that. Moreover, you could also very easily modify the page to steal user's cookies and send them conveniently to your server. So disabling submit behavior in the jsfiddle would make sense.